# Python Object via Function

Tags: python, arrays, inheritance, numpy, metaprogramming

I am trying to understand (and eventually use) the implementation of object arrays using record arrays from numpy from here: [Numpy object array](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.org/items/Obarray.html) in reviewing the code I am apparently learning new things about python and I can't seem to fully understand the following:

In the obarray.py file a function is used to create a new object and I am confused as to

1. Why a function is used,
2. How the arguments play into the function,
3. How using this function differs from creating the class with the arguments directly and (presumably using the arguments as attributes), and
4. What is this **main**.Obarray I get when I just call the function?

For 1 and 2 I have a hunch that the arguments somehow become that objects "local scope" and are perhaps similar to a object attribute?

Here is the code for the new object from the link:

```
import numpy as np
def make_obarray(klass, dtype):
    class Obarray(np.ndarray):
        def __new__(cls, obj):
            print "CLS:", cls
            print "OBJ:", obj
            A = np.array(obj,dtype=np.object)
            N = np.empty(shape=A.shape, dtype=dtype)
            for idx in np.ndindex(A.shape):
                for name, type in dtype:
                    N[name][idx] = type(getattr(A[idx],name))
            return N.view(cls)
        def __getitem__(self, idx):
            V = np.ndarray.__getitem__(self,idx)
            if np.isscalar(V):
                kwargs = {}
                for i, (name, type) in enumerate(dtype):
                     kwargs[name] = V[i]
                return klass(**kwargs)
            else:
                return V
        def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
            if isinstance(value, klass):
                value = tuple(getattr(value, name) for name, type in dtype)
            # FIXME: treat lists of lists and whatnot as arrays
            return np.ndarray.__setitem__(self, idx, value)
    return Obarray
```

Here is how I am testing it:

```
class Foo:
            def __init__(self, a, b):
                self.a = a
                self.b = b
            def __str__(self):
                return "<Foo a=%s b=%s>" % (self.a, self.b)
dtype = [("a",np.int),
                 ("b",np.float)]
FooArray = make_obarray(Foo, dtype)

A = FooArray([Foo(0,0.1),Foo(1,1.2),Foo(2,2.1),Foo(3,3.3)])
```

1. When I call FooArray I get `__main__.Obarray` - what is this?
2. What happened to "klass" and "dtype" that I entered as arguments?
3. How is this different from something along the lines of:

> Blockquote

```
class Obarray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls,input_array, klass, dtype):
       obj = np.assarray(input_array).view(cls) 
       obj.klass = klass
       obj.dtype = dtype
       A = np.array(obj,dtype=np.object)
       N = np.empty(shape=A.shape, dtype=dt ype)
       for idx in np.ndindex(A.shape):
            for name, type in dtype:
                N[name][idx] = type(getattr(A[idx],name))
       obj.N = N.view(np.ndarray) 
       return obj
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your confusion is specific to this `numpy` code or more general. Do you understand how closures work? Have you ever used a type-factory like `collections.namedtuple` before?

Comment: it's a more general question that came up in this code so I use it as my example.  Yes, I am familiar with namedtuple, however namedtuple's are immutable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `make_obarray` function is a factory that produces classes. The methods of the class's it returns will be closures that can access the function's local variables (e.g. the `klass` and `dtype` arguments) even after it has finished running.

Here's a much simpler closure that might help you understand how they work:

```
def make_adder(x):
    def adder(y):
        return x + y
    return adder
```

`make_adder` is a factory function. It returns an `adder` function which is a closure. `adder` can still see the `x` argument of the `make_adder` call in which it was defined, even after `make_adder` has returned.

This is simlar to the `numpy` code you've shown. The `make_obarray` function returns a class, rather than a function, but otherwise it's almost the same. The class's qualified name will be `some_module.Obarray` in Python 2 (or `some_module.make_obarray.<locals>.Obarray` in Python 3), where `some_module` is the name of the module it was defined in (or `__main__` if you've executed its module as a script). The methods of the returned class will be able to see the `klass` and `dtype` arguments passed into `make_obarray`, just like the `adder` function could see the `x` argument to `make_adder` in my simpler example.

As for *why* the code you've found is written that way, I couldn't say. Perhaps the code's author thought it would be useful to be able to use `isinstance` to distinguish between instances of `Obarray` with different `klass` or `dtype` values:

```
FooArray = make_obarray(Foo, dtype)
BarArray = make_obarray(Bar, some_other_dtype)

f = FooArray([Foo(1,2)])

print(isinstance(f, FooArray)) # True
print(isinstance(f, BarArray)) # False
```

If the `klass` and `dtype` were just arguments to a single class, you couldn't tell the difference between the array instances in this way (though you could probably come up with an equivalent check that compared the instances' attributes).